# Is it secure to use sshfs in conjunction with OwnCloud?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, apache-2.4, owncloud

I currently have an account with a Virtual Private Server (VPS) company - https://www.ovh.com/us/. On the virtual server I've rented from them I am running Debian Linux with OwnCloud and Apache installed. I've used sshfs to mount a remote filesystem at `/mnt/RemoteServer` using the command `sshfs user@My_IP_ddress:/mnt/HDD /mnt/RemoteServer/ -p 22 -o gid=33 -o uid=33 -o allow_other`. The UID and GID are set equal to the www-data user so that apache is able to have read/write access to the directory.

In my OwnCloud configuration, `owncloud/config.php`, I have specified my data directory as followed: `'datadirectory' => '/mnt/RemoteServer/owncloud'`.

Essentially what I've done is use the OVH to mount a website front end and reroute the data backend through the sshfs tunnel to another location for storage. I've used a signed ssl certificate to secure my site.

So far this has withstood the test of time. The sshfs is persistent and allows me to connect to my Owncloud site and upload files. I am, however, concerned with the integrity of my implementation.

- Is there anything innately insecure about my setup? Particularly with the use of sshfs to mount the remote file system.
- Does anyone have any resources that you could pass along in an effort to further my understanding of these types of implementations?
- Finally, are there better alternatives to my implementation that would be more secure given that I would like to retain the use of an ssh tunnel or similar solution.

Thank you in advance for your contribution!